# What's the good way to get an event target's siblings' value in React?

Tags: reactjs

```
function NewItem(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <input
                id = "content"
                placeholder = "add a new item..."
            />
            <input
                id = "score"
                placeholder = "score(points per hour)"
            />
            <button
                onClick = {
                    (e) => props.onAddItem(e)
                }
            >
                add
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The button click handler is implemented in father class, what I'm trying to do is when I click "add", the father class could be able to get the values of these two inputs, so that it could add an item in its "itemList" state. Is there a good way for me to get the values? I know I can manipulate DOM to do so, but I guess it's not a good way.

Below is the click handler and the render method of father class:

```
handleAddItem(e) {
    const newList = this.state.itemList;
    const itemCount = this.state.itemCount;
    newList.unshift({
        itemInfo: {
            content: ,
            score: ,
            time: ,
        }
        key: itemCount,
        index: itemCount,
    });
    this.setState({
        itemList: newList,
        itemCount: itemCount + 1,
    });
}


render() {
    return (
        <div id = "todo">
            <NewItem
                onAddItem = {
                    (e) => this.handleAddItem(e)
                }
            />
            <ItemList
                itemList = { this.state.itemList }
                onClick = {
                    (e) => this.handleDeleteItem(e)
                }
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> what I'm trying to do is when I click "add", the father class could be able to get the values of these two inputs

One solution is to wrap your inputs in a `<form>` and send it all together.

```
function NewItem(props) {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={props.onAddItem}>
            <input name="content"/>
            <input name="score"/>
            <button type="submit">add</button>
        </form>
    );
}

class Parent extends Component {
    handleAddItem(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const content = e.target.content.value;
        const score = e.target.score.value;
        // ...
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <NewItem onAddItem={this.handleAddItem}/>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out references or "refs". I generally avoid trying to use them, but sometimes it is just a cleaner way to deal with a problem.

Here's a snippet that might help you out.

```
import React from 'react'

class TestComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      controlledValue: 'controlled'
    }

    this._handleControlledChange = this._handleControlledChange.bind(this)
  }

  _handleControlledChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      controlledValue: e.target.value
    })
  }

  render(){
    return (
            <div>
            {/* Bind this to 'this.field1' */}
            <h3>Function Binding</h3>
            <input ref={f => this.field1 = f} />
            {/* bind this to this.refs.field2 */}
            <h3>Bind to Refs</h3>
            <input ref='field2' />

            <h3>Controlled Component</h3>
            <input 
              value={this.state.controlledValue} 
              onChange={this._handleControlledChange}
            />

            <button 
              onClick = {
                e => {
                  let field1Value = this.field1.value
                  let field2Value = this.refs.field2.value

                  alert('Field 1 ' + field1Value + '\n Field 2 ' + field2Value + '\nConrolled: ' + this.state.controlledValue )
                } 
              }
            >
            Ref test
            </button>

          </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Basically what's going on is I'm binding the component to the class so I can reference it later. Typically React code is going to depend on the state and not allowing components to manage themselves, but sometimes this is the behavior you want (a one off form or something you don't want to manage the state for).

Hopefully this helps. I demonstrated the three main ways you will likely want to control your components. Check out projects like https://material-ui.com/ and the tutorials for some more examples.

@wdm's form is a clever solution, I have not used that but I like it.